# Forms of non-stationary process

Tags: time-series, econometrics, stationarity

Is that true that non-stationary processes only includes trends, cycles, random walks, and combinations of the three?
If yes, has this statement been proofed?
If not, what are the other forms of non-stationary?

Comment: Do you have a reference for that statement?

Comment: No. This statement is only my guess after reading the webpage http://www.investopedia.com/articles/trading/07/stationary.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There are an infinite number of types of non-stationarity which you can easily dream up. For example, changing variance, changing skewness, level shifts, seasonality in the 6th moment, etc.

Also, cycles can be stationary. [Yule (1927)](http://rsta.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/226/636-646/267) studied cycles in sunspots using stationary AR(2) models, for example.

Comment: Sorry professor I was too exited... But how can I build models, which are specified to stationary processes, only after refusing hypothesis like unit root? As having no unit root, or etc., doesn't rule out the possibility of non-stationary. Is there any reading materials you would kindly recommend me?

Comment: You need to consider a specific class of stationary processes, such as ARMA processes. Read any good book on time series analysis such as Brockwell and Davis: http://amzn.com/0387953515/?tag=otexts-20

Answer (score 1):

> Is that true that non-stationary processes only includes trends, cycles, random walks, and combinations of the three?

Unless you define one of the three types or *combination* broader than I do, this would, exclude for example:

- Any superposition of a non-stationary process and a stationary process.
- Any process with a chaotic driver. Such a driver cannot be decomposed into periodic processes.
- If we are talking about discrete-time processes (as implied by *cycle*): Any process with a quasiperiodic driver.
- Any transient dynamics, i.e., a process that settles on (or asymptotically converges to) some stationary process after a while, e.g., a driven pendulum that takes some time to synchronise with its driver.